# Difference between short and less

Tags: word-usage

I have received ten boxes of poruduct . All boxes must have contained 200 pieces of product. But there were 185 pieces in the one of them. In this case would the sentences used with short,missing,less be correct and have the same meaning?

> I will send back the box with **short** amount.
>
> I will send back the box with **less** amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but neither of your examples are correct.

"Less" is a comparative term, so you could say that one of your boxes contains "*less than the others*", or "*less than it should*".

"Short" refers to the amount that you are *missing*, not the amount you have. Your box should contain 200 items, but it only contains 185, so it is *15 items short*. Idiomatically, you can just say that the box "is short".

I think "short" works better in this context. You could say any of the following (not an exhaustive list):

> - I will send back the box that is short.
> - I will send the short box back.

These use "less" if you really want to, but they don't sound quite as natural:

> I will send back the box that has less in than it should.
>
> I will send back the box that contains less than it should.

Comment: Actually what I thought is that the amount which the box has is 15 pieces short I mean the box with amount which is short. That is why I used “with”. So could it be undetstood by native speaker?